# How to hide page extension and $_GET values using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to hide page extension and `$_GET` value

```
http://localhost/dice_mpc/members.php?as=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
http://localhost/dice_mpc/home.php?as=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
http://localhost/dice_mpc/profile.php?as=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

Expectation result:

```
http://localhost/dice_mpc/members/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

Comment: You can't without tricks or redirection, .htaccess happens server-side, it can rewrite the URL so that the one applied in server differs from the one in the browser. You can rewrite `members` to `members.php` but if you type `http://localhost/dice_mpc/members` in browser, you'll have no parameter at all. One solution is to change $_GET parameters to $_POST, which are passed ouside of the URL

Comment: You can not “hide” the value of a GET parameter, if your script _needs_ that value in the first place.

Comment: what if something like this http://localhost/dice_mpc/members/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b  page name and id value

Comment: What if what? Ask a proper question.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the good duplicate (there are tons of questions about this) and in a good mood, so here we go:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^dice_mpc/(.+)/(.+)$ dice_mpc/$1.php?as=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**DETAILS:**

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` will prevent rewriting if you access to an existing folder
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will prevent rewriting if you access to an existing file
- `RewriteRule ^dice_mpc/(.+)/(.+)$ dice_mpc/$1.php?as=$2 [QSA,L]` will rewrite only URLS of format `{domain}/dice_mpc/{A}/{B}` so it won't redirect if `{B}` is not there. `{A}` will be converted to `{A}.php` and `{B}` to `?as={B}`
- `QSA` means query strings will be preserved (`{domain}/dice_mpc/{A}/{B}?test=1` will be rewritten to `{domain}/dice_mpc/{A}.php?as={B}&test=1`), and `L` means rewriting will stop here
- Don't forget to change your links to the new format, and be aware it may interact if you have other rewrite rules in your `.htaccess`

If this is not exactly what you want, please edit the question itself.